# mysql to mysqli function difficulties

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am converting this function:

```
function user_data($user_id) {
    $data = array();
    $user_id = (int)$user_id;

    $func_num_args = func_num_args();
    $func_get_args = func_get_args();

    if ($func_num_args > 1) {
        unset($func_get_args[0]);

        $fields = '`' . implode('`, `', $func_get_args) . '`';
        $data = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT $fields FROM `users` WHERE `user_id` = $user_id"));

        return $data;
    }
}
```

From mysql to mysqli however I am encountering difficulties wrapping my head around this and understanding why I'm not even getting any errors, here is my attempt at a mysqli version:

```
function user_data($user_id) {
    global $link;
    $data = array();
    $user_id = (int)$user_id;

    $func_num_args = func_num_args();
    $func_get_args = func_get_args();

    if ($func_num_args > 1) {
        unset($func_get_args[0]);

        $fields = '`' . implode('`, `', $func_get_args) . '`';
        $result = $link->query("SELECT $fields FROM `users` WHERE `user_id` = $user_id");

        if(!$result){
            printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $link->error);
        }else{
            while($data = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                print_r($data);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Any guidance or tips is much appreciated.

Comment: Post code for how you are calling the user_data() function.

Comment: I am testing it by simple using <?php user_data(25); ?>. 25 is just a user_id in my database.

Comment: Nope nevermind, I'm dumb.

Answer (score 0):

`if ($func_num_args > 1) {`

This line is preventing any of the enclosed code from being executed when you only pass one argument into the user_data() function. This function was designed to be passed a user id AND a list of columns to select data from in the users database table.

Instead of calling `user_data(25);`

try something like

`user_data(25, 'column_name1', 'column_name2');`